# FormRequest failed authorization laravel5.3/4

Tags: php, laravel

I try to authorize user via formRequest

```
public function authorize()
{
    return Gate::allows('users.create');
}
```

On failed validation I get 403 and page with error *HttpException in Handler.php line 133: This action is unauthorized.*. That's OK, but I want to create my own response in JSON. How can I do that? For failed validation i can use *response()*, but what if I want to handle failed authorization response?

I've found *failedAuthorization()*, but it returns *Excepiton*. Am i right that Laravel returns exception as a response (If debug mode is on)?

I need to authorize (or i rly prefer) user via *authorize()* method.

Answer (score 0):

According the the laravel documentation on authorization, you can handle a denial like so:

```
if (Gate::denies('update', $post)) {
    abort(403);
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authorization#policies

Comment: I can't do that. I need authorize user in *authorize()* method, who has to return boolean. If I try to return *response()* Laravel "get it" like a *boolean(true)*

Comment: @Ivan I override `failedAuthorization()` method in order to do that

Answer (score 0):

I override `failedAuthorization()` method to return a JSON response:

```php
    public function failedAuthorization()
    {
        throw new HttpResponseException(response()->json([
            'message' => 'You\'re not authorized to do this request',
            'exception' => 'This action requires more permissions'
        ], Response::HTTP_UNAUTHORIZED));
    }
```