# Redirect if request authorization is failed in Laravel

Tags: laravel-5, redirect, unauthorized

I am trying to redirect request if authorization is failed for it. I have following code:

```
class ValidateRequest extends Request{
    public function authorize(){
        // some logic here...
        return false;
    }

    public function rules(){ /* ... */}

    public function failedAuthorization() {
        return redirect('safepage');
    }
}
```

By default I am redirected to the 403 error page, but I would like to specify some specific route. I noticed that method `failedAuthorization()` is run, but `redirect()` method does not work...

Previously this code worked well with Laravel 5.1 but I used `forbiddenResponse()` method to redirect wrong request. How can I fix it with new LTS version?

Comment: Please check my below answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like it is impossible to `redirect()` directly from the custom `ValidateRequest` class. The only solution that I found is create custom exception and than handle it in the Handler class. So, now it works with following code:

**Update:** The method `redirectTo()` was updated to make solution work on Laravel 6.x and higher

**app/Requests/ValidateRequest.php**

```
class ValidateRequest extends Request{
    public function authorize(){
        // some logic here...
        return false;
    }

    public function rules(){
        return [];
    }

    public function failedAuthorization() {
        $exception = new NotAuthorizedException('This action is unauthorized.', 403);
        
        throw $exception->redirectTo("safepage");
    }
}
```

**app/Exceptions/NotAuthorizedException.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Exceptions;

use Exception;

class NotAuthorizedException extends Exception
{
    protected $route;

    public function redirectTo($route) {
        $this->route = $route;
    
        abort(Redirect::to($route));
    }
    
    public function route() {
        return $this->route;
    }
}
```

and **app/Exceptions/Handler.php**

```
...
public function render($request, Exception $exception){
    ...

    if($exception instanceof NotAuthorizedException){
            return redirect($exception->route());
        }

    ...
}
```

So, it works, but much more slower than I expected... Simple measuring shows that handling and redirecting take 2.1 s, but with Laravel 5.1 the same action (and the same code) takes only 0.3 s

Adding `NotAuthorizedException::class` to the `$dontReport` property does not help at all...

**Update**

It runs much more faster with php 7.2, it takes 0.7 s

Answer (score 2):

If you are revisiting this thread because in 2021 you are looking to redirect after failed authorization here's what you can do:

1. You cannot redirect from the failedAuthorization() method because it is expected to throw an exception (check the method in the base FormRequest class that you extend), the side effect of changing the return type is the $request hitting the controller instead of being handled on FormRequest authorization level.
2. You do not need to create a custom exception class, neither meddle with the Laravel core files like editing the render() of  app/Exceptions/Handler.php, which will pick up the exception you threw and by default render the bland 403 page.
3. All you need to do is throw new HttpResponseException()
   In the [Laravel reference API](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Http/Exceptions/HttpResponseException.html) we can see its job is to "Create a new HTTP response exception instance." and that is exactly what we want, right?

So we need to pass this Exception a $response. We can pass a redirect or JSON response!

Redirecting:

```
protected function failedAuthorization()
{
    throw new HttpResponseException(response()->redirectToRoute('postOverview')
        ->with(['error' => 'This action is not authorized!']));
}
```

So we are creating a new instance of the HttpResponseException and we use the [response() helper](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-response), which has this super helpful redirectToRoute('routeName') method, which we can further chain with the well known with() method and pass an error message to display on the front-end.

JSON:
Inspired by this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42096014/formrequest-failed-authorization-laravel5-3-4?fbclid=IwAR3VCKFWRK5TU3sLVBkc-t8nRXeye0tZcBStlybzMY4zwRXSBTznRdw3oDU)

```
throw new HttpResponseException(response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized action!'], 403));
```

Thats'it.
You don't have to make ANY checks for validation or authorization in your controller, everything is done in the background before it hits the controller. You can test this by putting a dd('reached controller'); at the top of your controller method and it shouln't get trigered.
This way you keep your controller thin and separate concerns :)

Sidenote:
forbiddenResponse() has been replaced after lara 5.4 with failedAuthorization()

Answer (score 0):

You can do through a middleware/policy i think. I don't know if you can do it from the validation.

You can override the function from FormRequest like this below:

```
   /**
     * Handle a failed authorization attempt.
     *
     * @return void
     *
     * @throws \Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException
     */
    protected function failedAuthorization()
    {
        throw new AuthorizationException('This action is unauthorized.');
    }
```

And redirect where you want.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But I already override `failedAuthorization()` as you can see in my example. Problem is that I cannot `redirect()` from this method... Looks like I need to create a custom exception...

Answer (score 0):

Answer for 2023 (Laravel v8++):

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

class MyCustomFormRequest extends Request
{
    public function authorize()
    {
        // check your logic, and:
        throw new \Illuminate\Http\Exceptions\HttpResponseException(
            redirect()->route('your route')->with('error', 'your error')
        );
    }
}
```

`HttpResponseException` is a [renderable exception](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/errors#renderable-exceptions), i.e. it accepts a response when created and the application will process said response - in this case redirect the browser.

The `authorize()` form request method is just one of the places where throwing it makes sense, but you can do it from almost anywhere.